# ¿Cómo obtener los nombre de las columnas de una tabla en Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

¿Existe alguna manera de obtener el nombre de las columnas de una tabla con el administrador objects en Django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los nombres en la base de datos son algo que se ve a nivel de la metadata del modelo, no del manager objects.

Si tu modelo se llama, por ejemplo, `Message`, primero sacamos los objetos fields del atributo `_meta`:

```py
fields = Message._meta.get_fields()
```

Esto es lo mismo que hacer

```py
fields = Message.objects.model._meta.get_fields()
```

Para sacar los nombres de las columnas en la base de datos:

```py
column_names = [field.get_attname_column()[1] for field in fields]
```

La función `get_attname_column()` devuelve una tupla de dos elementos, por ejemplo `('sender', 'sender')`. El segundo elemento de la tupla es el nombre real en la base de datos, normalmente va a ser igual al primer elemento a menos que hayas usado el parámetro `db_column` en tu Model Field. Puedes leer más [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5244198/2616577).

Lo acabo de probar con Django 3.0.4, pero debe funcionar con todas las versiones relativamente recientes (1.8+).